# intent from library project to main project

Tags: android, android-intent, android-library

When i try to pass **from the main project to library project** using intent **it works fine** but..... when i try to **pass from the library project to the main project, it doesn't recognize the class** in the main project.

i try to write in my library project this intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.example.uploadvideo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

i add to the manifests of both the main project and library project the two activities that i want to connect.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The library project does not know about the main project.
The prefered solution imo would be to use an action rather than trying to load the class directly in the intent. This will also give you more flexibility if you want to re-use the library.

So the library would do

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.action_video_upload");
intent.setPackage(mContext.getPackageName()); // only deliver to host app
```

and the main project would register for that intent in the manifest with

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <action android:name="com.example.action_video_upload" />
</intent-filter>
```

More information can be found here: [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: Is it possible that a different app on the same device using the same library would receive the action too?  If so, how can this conflict be prevented?

Comment: That is possible. Using intent.setPackageName() to the app package will restrict the broadcast to the current applicaton

Answer (score 2):

**Library projects** contain shareable Android source code and resources that you can reference in Android projects. This is useful when you have common code that you want to reuse. Library projects cannot be installed onto a device, however, they are pulled into the .apk file at build time.

In other words, library project are to be refrenced.

What make sense in calling an intent of your main project from library.

You are actually rendering library project inefficient to handle projects other than your current main project..

Comment: So you mean that is not possible to pass from library project to main using intent ?

Answer (score 1):

start next Activity as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,com.example.UploadVideo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

because currently you are passing wrong Activity name in second parameter to Intent constructor

Comment: @idan : currently u are passing `uploadvideo.class` instead of `UploadVideo.class`

Comment: @idan : and also make sure u are using this code inside an method.